# Laravel: Orderby in related table and with

Tags: php, laravel, sql-order-by, relation, eloquent

This is my model

- User
- Role

and relationship between of those models are many to many.

I want to create query like this:

```
return User::with('roles')->orderBy('roles.id')->paginate();
```

I don't want `join` because I created a base class for every model. I also don't want use `orderBy` after `get` because it must load all of my data and after that I should be able to sort and paginate it. So it is not a very good idea.

Comment: Without a join it's not possible (AFAIK).

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
return User::with(['roles'  => function ($query) {
        $query->orderBy('id', 'desc');
    }])->paginate();
```

But this will only order the eager loading attributes, but if you are interested to use join you can have something like this:

```
return User::with('roles')
    ->join('roles', 'user.id', '=', 'roles.user_id')
    ->orderBy('roles.id', 'desc')
    ->paginate();
```

In this you can easily use `paginate` which is your main concern.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
User::where('role_id','!=','0')->orderBy('role_id','DESC')->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers).